# Linear programming approach to dynamic programming - an initial pair of state-decisions

Tags: duality, column-generation, dynamic-programming, approximation-algorithms

I aim to solve the following Bellman equation:

\begin{equation}
    v(\vec{s}) = \min_{\vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}} \big\{c(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) + \lambda \times \sum_{\vec{s}^{'}\in S} p(\vec{s}^{'} | \vec{s}, \vec{x}) \times v(\vec{s}^{'})\big\}
    \hspace{2cm} \forall \vec{s} \in S
\end{equation}

I use the linear programming approach to solve the above equation like below:

**Model 1:**
\begin{equation}
   \max \Big\{\sum_{\vec{s} \in S} \eta(\vec{s}) \times v(\vec{s})\Big\}
\end{equation}
subjected to:
\begin{equation}
   c(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) + \lambda \times \sum_{\vec{s}^{'} \in S} p(\vec{s}^{'} | \vec{s}, \vec{x}) \times v(\vec{s}^{'}) \ge v(\vec{s}) \hspace{1cm}
    \forall \vec{s} \in S; \vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
   v(\vec{s}) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}
\end{equation}

Due to the curse of dimensionality, I use a basis function to approximate the value function and solve the dual of the above problem using a column generation (further detail can be found here: [10.1016/j.ejor.2012.06.046](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2012.06.046)). The column generation algorithm includes a master problem and a subproblem like below:

**Model 2,** Master problem: where the algorithm iteratively solves the dual problem - the shadow prices of constraints are equal to optimal approximation coefficients.

\begin{equation}
\min \sum_{\vec{s} \in S} \sum_{\vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}} c(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \times \chi(\vec{s}, \vec{x})
\end{equation}

subjected to:

\begin{equation}
(1 - \lambda) \times \sum_{\vec{s} \in S} \sum_{\vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}} \chi(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\vec{s} \in S} \sum_{\vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}} \mu_{koi}(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \times \chi(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \geq \mathbb{E}_{\eta} [p^w_{koi}] \hspace{1cm}
    \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\vec{s} \in S} \sum_{\vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}} \delta_{kti}(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \times \chi(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \geq \mathbb{E}_{\eta} [p^m_{kti}] \hspace{1cm}
    \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; t \in \mathcal{T}; i \in \mathcal{I}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\chi(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}
\end{equation}

**Model 3,** Sub-problem: where the algorithm finds feasible state-decision pairs to be added to the master problem.
\begin{equation}
\max \Big\{(1 - \lambda) \times V^0 +  \sum_{k \in \mathcal{K}} \sum_{o \in \mathcal{O}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} V^w_{koi} \times \mu_{koi}(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) + \sum_{k \in \mathcal{K}} \sum_{t \in \mathcal{T}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} V^m_{kti} \times \delta_{kti}(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) - c(\vec{s}, \vec{x})\Big\}
\end{equation}

subjected to:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}^w} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} \sum_{t \in \mathcal{T}} \sum_{\substack{b \in \mathcal{B}_c \\ c \in \mathcal{C}}} z_{pjtib} \times R^1_{pk} \times R^1_{po} \leq p^w_{koi}
    \hspace{1cm} \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}^m} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} \sum_{\substack{b \in \mathcal{B}_c \\ c \in \mathcal{C}}} z_{pjtib} \times R^1_{pk} = p^m_{kti}
    \hspace{1cm} \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; t \in \mathcal{T}; i \in \mathcal{I}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \in S \times \Xi_{\vec{s}}
\end{equation}

My problem starts from here! To initiate the column generation algorithm, I need to have at least one feasible pair of state-decision for **Model 2**. As suggested by [Saure et al. (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2012.06.046), I iteratively solve **Models 4 and 3** until the objective function of **Model 4** becomes equal to zero (meaning that a set of feasible state-decisions is found for **Model 2** so I can start the column generation). Starting from an initial hypothesized state, I solve **Model 4**, finds the shadow prices of constraints and update $V^0$, $V^w_{koi}$ and $V^m_{kti}$, and solve **Model 3** (to update $P$ for **Model 4**). Solving **Models 4 and 3** for a few iterations, the objective of **Model 4** improves for a while. However, **Model 3** stops providing new outcomes for decision variables (generates an identical solution).

What would be the reason for this issue?

Let me know if you need further information.

**Model 4:**

\begin{equation}
\min \Big\{U^0 + \sum_{k \in \mathcal{K}} \sum_{o \in \mathcal{O}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} U^w_{koi} + \sum_{k \in \mathcal{K}} \sum_{t \in \mathcal{T}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} U^m_{kti}\Big\} 
\end{equation}

Subjected to:

\begin{equation}
(1 - \lambda) \times \sum_{\vec{s} \in P} \sum_{\vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}} \chi(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) + U^0 = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\vec{s} \in P} \sum_{\vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}} \mu_{koi}(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \times \chi(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) + U^w_{koi} \geq \mathbb{E}_{\eta} [p^w_{koi}] \hspace{1cm}
    \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; o \in \mathcal{O}; i \in \mathcal{I}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\vec{s} \in P} \sum_{\vec{x} \in \Xi_{\vec{s}}} \delta_{kti}(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) \times \chi(\vec{s}, \vec{x}) + U^m_{kti} \geq \mathbb{E}_{\eta} [p^m_{kti}] \hspace{1cm}
    \forall k \in \mathcal{K}; t \in \mathcal{T}; i \in \mathcal{I}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
U^0, U^w_{koi}, U^m_{kti} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}
\end{equation}